# HTML5 Form Validation Initial "Tooltip" Message

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, tooltip

I'm looking for a way to set the initial message of the "tooltip" that pops-up when an element got the `required` attribute.
The message text is localised, so when the language is non English, it gives an unfinished appearance.

The code that changes/displays the validation message is the following:

```
    document.querySelector("#imIn").addEventListener("change", function (e) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity("");
        e.target.checkValidity();
    });

    document.querySelector("#imIn").addEventListener("invalid", function(e) {
        e.target.setCustomValidity(window.app.selectCountryText);
    });
```

- Initially when hovering

[image: On hover]

- When triggering the validation

[image: Trigger validation message]

- After validation: "tooltip" message is set to the same as validation message
  [image: After validation]
- But in (i.e.) Swedish it becomes this:

[image: Not so Swedish]

- And after the validation is triggered:

[image: Swedish after validation]

Is there any way to set the initial text or any suggested fix?

Answer (score 1):

in short, when the page loads, set the custom validity to a single space. This removes the 'tooltip'

The challenge is, that if you don't set an initial custom validity message, then a default is used...and the default isn't always appropriate.

If you want to replace the default, set a custom validity message for the field when your page initially loads - for example, you might attach a function to your body's onloaded action as demonstrated here:

```
<body onload="init()">
   ...your web page here
</body>
<script>
   function init(){
      document.querySelector("#imIn").setCustomValidity('your default message');
   }
</script>
```

This will run as your page loads, replacing the built-in default text with your own.

THAT SAID... I do understand your challenge!  If you don't already know the user's language when the page loads, then you wouldn't know what language to display that custom validity in. So, I'd suggest that you consider **setting the custom validity to a single space** which is enough to wipe out the inappropriate default message entirely, without generating any other message (the 'tooltip
will not show at all).

You might wish to do this for all of your input fields in one easy block of code as follows:

```
   [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'), (e)=>{
      e.setCustomValidity(' ');
   });
```

This code might go into the init() function shown above, instead of the line setting  the validity message to 'your default message'.

of course on subsequent reloads of the page, you probably now have the user's language choice stored in the querystring, cookie or session so you can adapt your code to use the single space approach on if you don't have the info needed to calculate a language-sensitive message.

Be aware - as it stands, that this method does set the input field's validity flag to false and will activate any css which specifically targets invalid fields.  This can be overcome by following your setCustomValidity(' ') instruction with a request for the validity of the field to be re-assessed using the checkValidity(); Because the field is not REALLY invalid, this should mark it as valid. Normally this will reverse any ill effects of having triggered the validity issue with your custom single-space validity message and will leave you with a form ready to use, and with none of the inbuilt tooltips.

**THE FINAL CODE:**

```
<body onload="init()">
   ...your web page here
</body>
<script>
   function init(){
      [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input'), (e)=>{
         e.setCustomValidity(' ');
         e.checkValidity();
      });
   }
</script>
```